# How to get the checked values from browser in angular2(facing ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Error)

Tags: angular, checkbox, typescript

im trying to get the values of check boxes which are checked below is my html code and im facing below error when im trying to achieve this

**ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

```
> <input type="checkbox" name="options"
> (click)="checkvalues(files)"></td>
```

checkvalues() method in typescript

```
checkvalues(filesinput:any){
        this.entries.push(filesinput);
        console.log(this.entries);
    }
```

Please help me out

Comment: Doesn't look like the error message is related to the code you posted. Perhaps in `checkvalues()`?

Comment: Can you provide the checkvalues(files) method?

Comment: im unable to reach the checkvalues function in typescript . when i click on the check box im getting the above errror                                                             Here is my checkvalues() method                                                                          checkvalues(filesinput:any){
        this.entries.push(filesinput);
        console.log(this.entries);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your `this.entries` is not defined?!

Try this:

```js
checkvalues(filesinput:any) {
   if (!this.entries) this.entries = [];
   this.entries.push(filesinput);
   console.log(this.entries);
}
```